# How is 8 rakat Tahajjud prayed in Hanafi fiqh?

Tags: salat, hanafi, tahajjud

There are many videos in youtube and articles in the Net about Tahajjud salah in Hanafi fiqh and they make different confusing statements. Here are some of them:

> In Hanafi fiqh Tajahhud is 8 rakats
>
> In Hanafi fiqh Tajahhud is 8 rakats by 2
>
> In Hanafi fiqh Tajahhud is 8 rakats by 2 with one Salam
>
> In Hanafi fiqh Tajahhud is 8 rakats with one Salam

And I understand them like this (in 3 ways),

**1st WAY**

```
 [Beginning of Salah]
 - Niyyah (for 8 rakats), Takbeer, Sana, Ta-'awwuz
 1 Tasmiyah, Fatiha, Sura, Ruku', Sajda
 2 Tasmiyah, Fatiha, Sura, Ruku', Sajda
 3 Tasmiyah, Fatiha, Sura, Ruku', Sajda
 4 Tasmiyah, Fatiha, Sura, Ruku', Sajda
 5 Tasmiyah, Fatiha, Sura, Ruku', Sajda
 6 Tasmiyah, Fatiha, Sura, Ruku', Sajda
 7 Tasmiyah, Fatiha, Sura, Ruku', Sajda
 8 Tasmiyah, Fatiha, Sura, Ruku', Sajda
 - Tashahhud
 - Salawat, Dua, Salam
 [End of Salah]
```

**2nd WAY**

```
 [Beginning of Salah]
 - Niyyah (for 8 rakats), Takbeer, Sana, Ta-'awwuz
 1 Tasmiyah, Fatiha, Sura, Ruku', Sajda
 2 Tasmiyah, Fatiha, Sura, Ruku', Sajda
 - Tashahhud
 3 Tasmiyah, Fatiha, Sura, Ruku', Sajda
 4 Tasmiyah, Fatiha, Sura, Ruku', Sajda
 - Tashahhud
 5 Tasmiyah, Fatiha, Sura, Ruku', Sajda
 6 Tasmiyah, Fatiha, Sura, Ruku', Sajda
 - Tashahhud
 7 Tasmiyah, Fatiha, Sura, Ruku', Sajda
 8 Tasmiyah, Fatiha, Sura, Ruku', Sajda
 - Tashahhud
 - Salawat, Dua, Salam
 [End of Salah]
```

**3rd WAY**

```
 [Beginning of Salah]
 - Niyyah (for 2 rakats), Takbeer, Sana, Ta-'awwuz
 1 Tasmiyah, Fatiha, Sura, Ruku', Sajda
 2 Tasmiyah, Fatiha, Sura, Ruku', Sajda
 - Tashahhud
 - Salawat, Dua, Salam
 [End of Salah]

 [Beginning of Salah]
 - Niyyah (for 2 rakats), Takbeer, Sana, Ta-'awwuz
 1 Tasmiyah, Fatiha, Sura, Ruku', Sajda
 2 Tasmiyah, Fatiha, Sura, Ruku', Sajda
 - Tashahhud
 - Salawat, Dua, Salam
 [End of Salah]

 [Beginning of Salah]
 - Niyyah (for 2 rakats), Takbeer, Sana, Ta-'awwuz
 1 Tasmiyah, Fatiha, Sura, Ruku', Sajda
 2 Tasmiyah, Fatiha, Sura, Ruku', Sajda
 - Tashahhud
 - Salawat, Dua, Salam
 [End of Salah]

 [Beginning of Salah]
 - Niyyah (for 2 rakats), Takbeer, Sana, Ta-'awwuz
 1 Tasmiyah, Fatiha, Sura, Ruku', Sajda
 2 Tasmiyah, Fatiha, Sura, Ruku', Sajda
 - Tashahhud
 - Salawat, Dua, Salam
 [End of Salah]
```

**Which way is correct in Hanafi fiqh?**

Comment: Can you link to where you heard these statements?

Comment: You don't need the links if you want to answer. I made my post as simple as possible.

Comment: I don't know the answer. But, I want to see what these different sources you found were. Perhaps you misunderstood them.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't save the links. Anyway, they were not in English.

Comment: I misunderstand them and getting confused. This is the reason I am posting this question

Comment: I'm not sure about the validity of the first. The other two are both correct, although I think the second is considered better. Although it is generally better to extend qirat rather than increasing the number of rakaats. So what I do is read two, and extend qirat as l long as I feel like, especially for Tahajjud when nobody is around to disrupt my focus. This is all according to Hanafi fiqh.

Comment: There are many demo videos but only for 2 rakat tahajjud. And I don't see a logic in the 3rd way. As one of the requirements for tahajjud is that it must be preceded by a sleep. Taking this into account, in 3rd way one has to sleep 4 times, don't u think?

Comment: @Muslim You misunderstand. Not every set from tahajjud needs to be preceded by sleep. It's just that tahajjud as a whole needs to be after you slept and woke up.

Comment: Ok, which way is correct?

Comment: @Muslim I've only ever known the third way. But, Idk if it is specifically the Hanafi method of doing it. As far as I know, it is for everyone.

Comment: If you're just gonna keep making minor edits to this post in order to bump it to the front page, I'm just gonna delete it. If you want to promote your question, post a bounty. Otherwise, be patient and wait for an answer like everyone else.

Answer (score 1):

The chosen position of the Hanafi school and the position of the two companions of Abu Hanifah (RA) is that the best way to perform them is with sets of 2 rakahs each set ending in Salam.

It is written in Ad-Darr Al-Mukhtar the well-known Hanafi book of fiqh:

> وتُكْرَهُ الزِّيادَةُ عَلى أرْبَعٍ فِي نَفْلِ النَّهارِ، وعَلى
> ثَمانٍ لَيْلًا بِتَسْلِيمَةٍ لِأنَّهُ لَمْ يَرِدْ (والأفْضَلُ فِيهِما الرُّباعُ بِتَسْلِيمَةٍ) وقالا: فِي اللَّيْلِ المَثْنى أفْضَلُ، قِيلَ وبِهِ يُفْتى
>
> It is disliked to increase over 4 rakahs in Nafl during the day and over 8 rakahs at night with one Salam because it has not been received (from the Prophet).
>
> And the best during both (day and night) is 4 rakahs with one Salam. And the two (companions of Abu Hanifah) said: In the night, pairs are better; And this is the chosen opinion.

This means the 3rd method mentioned in your question is the chosen opinion of the Hanafi school as the best way to do it. Although, as the quote demonstrates, it is allowed without being disliked to the Hanafis to pray all 8 rakahs together, it is not the best choice.

Praying in pairs is also the position of the other 3 schools, and the Hanbalis said it is the only allowed way to do it.

Their evidence is much, but one of the ahadith is:

> The Prophet (ﷺ) said, "Salat during the night should consist of pairs of but if you fear that morning is near, then pray one Rak'ah as Witr." ([Bukhari and Muslim](https://sunnah.com/riyadussalihin:1168))

As for how to pray the 8 rakahs together, that would be like your second method because the position of the Hanafi school is that the Tashahhud is wajib at the end of every two rakahs even during Nafl prayers.

I don't know who would recommend the first method as ideal. Probably, you misunderstood.

Comment: Thank you for your effort, brother. However, my research is favoring the 2nd way. I will make some edits to my post as soon as I have time.

Comment: @Muslim What sources said it is better to pray all 8 rakahs together?